# Firebase CLI v10.0.1 is incompatible with Node.js v10.24.1 Please upgrade Node.js >=12

Tags: node.js, firebase, incompatibility

I am facing this issue while deploying my firebase function through Git Actions

```
Firebase CLI v10.0.1 is incompatible with Node.js v10.24.1 Please upgrade Node.js to version >= 12
```

My Firebase version:9.16.6
Node version : 14.15.4..

---

**Edit:** Here is the `dependencies` section of my `package.json` file.

```json
"dependencies": {
  "axios": "^0.21.1",
  "cryptr": "^6.0.2",
  "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
  "fetch": "^1.1.0",
  "firebase": "^8.10.0",
  "firebase-admin": "^9.8.0",
  "firebase-functions": "^3.16.0",
  "lodash": "^4.17.21",
  "node-fetch": "^2.6.1",
  "request": "^2.88.2",
  "request-promise": "^4.2.6"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "eslint": "^7.6.0",
  "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
  "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0"
}
```

Comment: The same message just happened to my latest build on circleci.

Comment: Can you share your `package.json`, or at least the `dependencies` section from it?

Comment: Ok...Will share package.json with you @Mureinik

Comment: "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "cryptr": "^6.0.2",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "fetch": "^1.1.0",
    "firebase": "^8.10.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^9.8.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.16.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.1",
    "request": "^2.88.2",
    "request-promise": "^4.2.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^7.6.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0"
  },

Answer (score 1):

i added https://github.com/actions/setup-node to my workflow (this probably isnt required). And changed `w9jds/firebase-action@x.x.x` to `w9jds/firebase-action@master` (Changed specific version to master`. This fixed it for me. I hope it works!

Comment: FYI the path to your Github Action workflow is usually: `<repo>/.github/workflows/main.yml`.

Answer (score 0):

Check node version in circleci or any other that you are using.
I got same exact error and upgraded node version in .circleci/config.yml and it's working now.

Answer (score -1):

I solved this by downloading and installing the newest version of Node.js on my PC from nodejs.org